# What is a changelist in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

What is a changelist in IntelliJ IDEA? Is it similar to a commit? When adding one, I have the following options:

- Name (text field)
- Comment (text field)
- Make this changelist active (checkbox)
- Track context (checkbox)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462378/what-is-a-changelist-in-intellj-idea-a-list-of-changes-compared-to-what-an-ac gives some additional information.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-changelists.html

Answer (score 75):

[Changelists](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/changelist.html), when used with Git, is a way to split your index (i.e. the files you have added to git) into logical filesets. See [Using Git Locally with IntelliJ IDEA](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Using_Git_Locally_with_IntelliJ_IDEA#Committing_Changes_to_Master_.28Revision_1.29)

Those changelists can represent whatever you want (a task, a fix, a merge etc), but they are not git commits.

You can commit one or several changelists.

[image: default changelist]

When you add a file to the Git Index, IntelliJ IDEA adds your file to the default changelist, named... "default".

Comment: Could you suggest any Git GUI have **changelists** function like IntelliJ IDEA ?

Comment: Here is another source about [Managing Changelists](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-changelists.html)

Comment: So is it IDEA feature only? Can I manage change lists in a terminal, for example?

Comment: @xotonic I am not aware of a CLI command able to manipulate IntelliJ IDEA change list (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-changelists.html).