# IntelliJ change lists without source control

Tags: intellij-idea, rational-team-concert

We are being forced to work with Rational Team Concert [RTC] source control, which has very weak integration with IntelliJ (There is an IntelliJ plugin, but it's just buggy and extremely painful to work with).
So I plan to manage the source control outside IntelliJ using the windows shell extension or the eclipse plugin console.

Is it possible to manage IntelliJ change lists manually without connecting with any source control?
The only solution that I could think of so far, is having a mock SVN server to connect IntelliJ to, but this has many downsides to it...

Please help, I don't want to move to Eclipse :\

Answer (score 1):

What I usually see is the use of an intermediate SCM tool which can interface with IntelliJ without disrupting the target SCM used (here RTC, through a local workspace or sandbox)

For instance, you can use git, as in "[In git, what is a changelist?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11070704/6309)".

[image: git changes]

Once you are ready to commit, you can refresh your pending changes view in IntelliJ IDEA (if you are using the "[JazzConnect-IntelliJ](http://www.cm-logic.com/software/jazzconnect-intellij.html)")

[image: pending changes]

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to work with intermediate git instance and the RTC SCM? can I deliver git changes to the RTC SCM? I didn't quite understand how the two can co exist. Thanks!

Comment: @Ido.Co they simply ignore each others. (there is a bridge RTC-git though, but it is costly). The idea is simply to allow you to work with another VCS, up until you need to commit/deliver with RTC.