# What is changelist in Git/IntelliJ and how to get rid of it?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, changelist

If I am commiting code in IntelliJ with Git, I see the following dialog:

[image]

As you see, it has `Change list` set to "Recovering from unsuccessfull...". This is my title, created long time ago and I don't know how to use it.

So, I would like to remove this title from the dialog.

But if I change it to "Default", then I get empty window:

[image]

What all these things mean and how to get rid of old change list title, still being able to commit code?

Comment: For a description of change lists: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21463286/2730610

Basically it looks like you have that "Recovering from..." set as your active changelist, you'll want to move changes over to default and set it as active

Comment: Changelists are basically an IDE replacement (or model of) the staging area in git, allowing you to work on multiple tasks in the same work area, and commit them separately. They're a great boon to working in `svn`, since `svn` does not support this directly; but if you're already familiar with the `git` command-line, it might make more sense to use it directly.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> What all these things mean and how to get rid of old change list
>   title, still being able to commit code?

First off, you should move your changes from the old changelist to the default one. In order to do that, go to `View | Tool Windows | Version Control` or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> in windows:

[image]
<sup>*Version Control Panel*</sup>
Then select the old changelist title and drag it to the default one or use **Move to Another Changelist** button. After you moved changes to the default changelist, just right click on the old one and select **Delete** option.

> What is changelist in Git/IntelliJ and how to get rid of it?

Checkout the IntelliJ's documentation on [Changelist](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/changelist.html) and [Managing Changelist](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/managing-changelists.html).